# Best way to .skip() in a foreign list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 tables:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserNotification> ApplicationUserNotifications { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserNotification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show the first 10 notifications for the user and use the same view to load the next 10 notifications when the user scrolls down.

```
public ActionResult UserNotications(int skip = 0, int take = 10)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var list = user.ApplicationUserNotifications.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    return View(list);
}
```

But is says:

'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Skip(IQueryable, int)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

What's the best way to solve this without changing the code to directly query from the usernotification table? The actual usage of this code uses the user class, so it would be better if I can access the usernotifications through the user object.

It's weird I would have expected there would be a lot of questions about this, but searchengines seem to skip the word "skip" so I can't find anything about this.

=====================

Update for mick, I use it in a view and I have a static object where I can access the user object called "Current":

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var skip = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Skip"] ?? "0");
    var take = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Take"] ?? "10");
}

@foreach (var item in Current.User.UserNotifications.Skip(skip).Take(take))
{
    @Html.Partial(Enum.GetName(typeof(Kiteshoot.Enums.NotificationType), item.NotificationType), item)
}

<div class="UserNotificationsEndOfList" data-index="@(skip + take)"></div>
```

I really dont know why but the error has magicly disapeared, I've been coding too long I think, sorry. But as Stijn called, this won't skip the query, but just the in-memory list, so back to square one.

Comment: I know how lazy loading works, but I want it to lazy load and skip, should be possible I'd think. The .ToList() solution is not acceptable sorry. Like I said in the question I can do: var list = db.ApplicationUserNotifications.Where(a => a.ApplicationUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()); But I need this functionallity somewhere where I only receive the ApplicationUser object.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time! (bedankt ;)

Comment: Can you supply the relevant portions of the code for the ApplicationDbContext, such that its a complete example.  And change the type declarations of user and list, so that its obvious what type they are.  There's no way to determine the type of these variables from your code.

Comment: Skip and Take are available on the ApplicationUserNotifications property of  the ApplicationUser class you've posted.

Comment: @Mick oh you're right, `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so Skip and Take should be available. Still, it would result in pulling the entire collection in memory.

Comment: @Stijn it is possible to use Skip and Take in Entity Framework without pulling the entire collection in memory

Comment: @Mick but not when using the navigation property, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use skip and take to load only a portion of the notifications from the database use...

```
DbSet<ApplicationUserNotification>()
    .Where(n => n.ApplicationUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
    .Skip(() => skip)
    .Take(() => take)
    .ToList()
```

If you're wondering why .Skip(() => skip) instead of .Skip(skip) try out both and look at the SQL generated using SQL Profiler or some other query monitoring tool.  You'll see .Skip(() => skip) results in a parameterised query, whereas .Skip(skip).Take(take) will bake the values for skip and take into the query text, which will reduce hits on the SQL plan cache, resulting in poorer performance when paging.